# Running this calculation adds an extra decimal point

Tags: c#, math, rounding

I'm running the following calculation and for some reason, an extra decimal is added to the result:

```cs
decimal bal = 10.0000
decimal totAmount = 15.0000
decimal payAmount = 3

tempAmount = Math.Ceiling((decimal)(bal / totAmount) * payAmount * 100);
tempAmount = tempAmount / 100;

// tempAmount results in 2.01 as opposed to 2.00
```

Am I running this incorrectly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Am I running this incorrectly?

No, but you're introducing an intermediate value (10m/15m) which can't be precisely represented as a `decimal`. It's being rounded up to 0.6666666666666666666666666667, which then leads to the problem.

If you perform the division as the *last* operation, you can avoid that, at least in this case:

```cs
using System;

decimal bal = 10.0000m;
decimal totAmount = 15.0000m;
decimal payAmount = 3;

decimal tempAmount = Math.Ceiling((bal * payAmount * 100m) / totAmount);
tempAmount = tempAmount / 100;

Console.WriteLine(tempAmount);
```

That prints out 2 instead of 2.01.

Answer (score 3):

Well, let's have a look at the computations

```
decimal bal = 10.0000m;
decimal totAmount = 15.0000m;
decimal payAmount = 3m;

decimal tempAmount = Math.Ceiling((decimal)(bal / totAmount) * payAmount * 100);
```

*step by step*:

```
bal / totAmount                                            == 
   0.6666666666666666666666666667m (note the last 7 due to rounding)

(decimal)(bal / totAmount) * payAmount                     == 
   2.0000000000000000000000000001m (note the very last 1)

(decimal)(bal / totAmount) * payAmount * 100               == 
   200.00000000000000000000000001m (note the very last 1)

Math.Ceiling((decimal)(bal / totAmount) * payAmount * 100) == 
  201m
```

Finally, when you divide `201` by `100` you'll get **2.01**